# Windows Phone 8 Button in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone 8 application. In DataTemplate I have two textblocks and button.
in first textblock I binding a Name field, in other I try to write "hello world" (or some other string) when i clicked the button.

I try like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="testListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,118"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding test}" Margin="0,43,10,68"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,88,0,0"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>


    class DevicesClass
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void devicesMethod(JObject bla)
    {

            List<DevicesClass> AllDevicesList = new List<DevicesClass>();

            foreach (JToken devices in bla["devices"])
            {
                DevicesClass AllDevices = new DevicesClass() { Name = devices["name"].ToString() };
                AllDevicesList.Add(AllDevices);
             }    
this.testListBox.ItemsSource = AllDevicesList;}


 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        light.test = "HelloWorld";
        DataContext = light;     
    }
```

When I tap the button nothing happens. I want some proposals how I can do this.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get your `TextBlock Element In DataTemplate` & Set its Text;

```
<ListBox x:Name="testListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,118"></TextBlock>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding test}" Margin="0,43,10,68"></TextBlock>
                     <Button Content="Test" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,88,0,0"></Button>
               </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In Your Event;

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var buttonElement = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
     var rootParent = (Grid)buttonElement.Parent;
     var yourTextBlock = (TextBlock)rootParent.Children.ElementAt(1);
     yourTextBlock.Text = "Hello, World!";
}
```

Do debug your Button Event Handler & See you are getting the correct elements.
See if this helps.

Comment: This solve my problem and answer on many other questions. Thanks alot!